# How to pass environment variable to an AutoLoaded mod_perl handler, to be used at module load time?

Tags: perl, apache, mod-perl2

I have a HTTP Request Handler for mod_perl which needs to read an environment variable, from `%ENV`, at module load time. The environment variable is passed from the Apache config into mod_perl using the [`PerlSetEnv`](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/config/config.html#C_PerlSetEnv_) directive.

This worked fine, until we changed the Apache configuration to [AutoLoad](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/config/config.html#C_AutoLoad_) the handler at startup time, for performance reasons. When the module is AutoLoaded like this, the`PerlSetEnv` does not take effect at module load time, and the variable we need is only available from `%ENV` at request time inside the handler method.

**Is there a way to continue using AutoLoad, but still set an environment variable in the Apache config which is available in Perl's `%ENV` at module load time?**

### Minimal example:

Here's a stripped down test-case to illustrate the problem.

The Apache config **without** autoload enabled:

```
PerlSwitches -I/home/day/modperl
<Location /perl>
    SetHandler modperl
    PerlSetEnv TEST_PERLSETENV 'Does it work?'
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Test
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Contents of /home/day/modperl/ModPerl/Test.pm:

```
package ModPerl::Test;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Apache2::RequestRec ();
use Apache2::RequestIO ();
use Apache2::Const qw(OK);

my %ENV_AT_MODULE_LOAD = %ENV; # Take a copy

sub handler {
    my $r = shift;
    $r->content_type('text/plain');

    $r->print("ENV:\n");
    foreach my $key (sort keys %ENV) {
        $r->print("  $key: $ENV{$key}\n");
    }   

    $r->print("ENV_AT_MODULE_LOAD:\n");
    foreach my $key (sort keys %ENV_AT_MODULE_LOAD) {
        $r->print("  $key: $ENV_AT_MODULE_LOAD{$key}\n");
    }   

    return OK;
}   
1;
```

When localhost/perl is viewed in the browser, I see this:

```
ENV:
  MOD_PERL: mod_perl/2.0.5
  MOD_PERL_API_VERSION: 2
  PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
  TEST_PERLSETENV: Does it work?
ENV_AT_MODULE_LOAD:
  MOD_PERL: mod_perl/2.0.5
  MOD_PERL_API_VERSION: 2
  PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
  TEST_PERLSETENV: Does it work?
```

*Hooray!* `TEST_PERLSETENV` is available at module load time, as we want.

**But** when we change the Apache config to enable Autoload (by using + in the PerlResponseHandler like so):

```
    PerlResponseHandler +ModPerl::Test
```

I get the following output instead:

```
ENV:
  MOD_PERL: mod_perl/2.0.5
  MOD_PERL_API_VERSION: 2
  PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
  TEST_PERLSETENV: Does it work?
ENV_AT_MODULE_LOAD:
  MOD_PERL: mod_perl/2.0.5
  MOD_PERL_API_VERSION: 2
  PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

*Boo!* `TEST_PERLSETENV` is no longer available at module load time :( How can I get it back while keeping the AutoLoad behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argh, 30 seconds after posting this question, I found the answer. Thank you [rubber duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html).

Move the `PerlSetEnv` to before the `<Location>` block which contains the `PerlResponseHandler` directive, and it works again!

i.e. like this:

```
PerlSwitches -I/home/dbarr/modperl
PerlSetEnv TEST_PERLSETENV 'Does it work?'
<Location /perl>
    SetHandler modperl
    PerlResponseHandler +ModPerl::Test
    Allow from all
</Location>
```